# SwiftUI error: "List failed to visit cell content, returning an empty cell."

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

I saw this error after I made a huge change to my app's code. I wonder if anyone knows what it means and if it's OK to ignore it.

> List failed to visit cell content, returning an empty cell. - SwiftUI/UICollectionViewListCoordinator.swift:296 - please file a bug report.

It occurred when I popped up a view containing a `List` from `NavigationStack`. I used `List` a lot in my code. I identified the exact `List` causing the error by changing each `List` to `VStack` one by one and saw if the error message was gone. However, I really can't see any issue in my code that could cause such an error. Also, I can't reproduce the error with a simple example (though the error can be reproduced in my app consistently).

I'm asking here because when the error showed up my app crashed. I later fixed the crash issue somehow but the above error message still persisted. So I suspected the crash and the above error message were two separate issues, but I'm not sure. Searching for the error message comes up with very few results. So I wonder if it's just me or it's a common issue? Thanks.

---

UPDATE: Forgot to mention, the view which I suspect caused the issue works fine usually. It only generates the error in a very specific scenario when I pop up the view from navigation stack. In the three possible reasons that @ahmed-maher list, I think item 1 and 2 are unlikely in my case because otherwise the error message should show up in the first place. I'm not sure about item 3, though I don't think the cell's content is complex (it contains just some texts, organized by `HStack` and `VStack`).

Comment: My guess is not using List/ForEach `id` correctly

Comment: I agree with malhal. I had the same problem of a list showing the empty cell warning. After setting the id to a unique value the list showed correctly.

Answer (score 3):

It's due to a bug with SwiftUI `List` section header. I was aware section header is very buggy when it is changed programmatically (especially when its layout is also changed), but didn't expect it might cause random crash. After I replaced the header with static content, the crash is completed gone and the "empty cell" error message is almost gone (it becomes hard to reproduce it, thought it still occurrs). I'll call it a day and consider to replace `List` with `LazyVStack` in future.